# Nginx install intermediate certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificate

I'm trying to install an intermediate certificate on Nginx ( laravel forge ).
Right now the certificate is properly installed, just the intermediate that is missing.

I've seen that I need to concatenate the current certificate with the intermediate. What is the best/safest way to add the intermediate certificate.

Also, if the install of the intermediate failed, can I just roll back to the previous certificate, and reboot nginx? ( the website site is live, so I can't have a too long downtime )

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Nginx expects all `server` section certificates in a file that you refer with `ssl_certificate`. Just put all vendor's intermediate certificates and your domain's certificate in a file. It'll look like this.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

To make sure everything is okay and to avoid downtime, I would suggest you to setup Nginx locally, add `127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com` to `/etc/hosts`, and try open it from major browsers. When you've verified that everything is correct your can replicate it to the production server.

When you're done, it is a good idea to use some SSL checker tool to verify (e.g. [this one](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)). Because pre-installed CA certificates may vary depending on browser and platform, you can easily overlook a misconfiguration checking from one OS or a limited set of browsers.

## Edit

As @Martin pointed out, the order of certificates in the file is important.
[RFC 4346](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-7.4.2) for TLS 1.1 states:

> This is a sequence (chain) of X.509v3 certificates.  The sender's
> certificate must come first in the list.  Each following
> certificate must directly certify the one preceding it.

Thus the order is:

- 1. Your domain's certificate
- 2. Vendor's intermediate certificate that certifies (1)
- 3. Vendor's intermediate certificate that certifies (2)
- ...
- n. Vendor's root certificate that certifies (n-1). Optional, because it should be contained in client's CA store.

Comment: Please note that the order is important, see https://serverfault.com/questions/476576/how-to-combine-various-certificates-into-single-pem/476620#476620

Comment: I tried this method but my nginx isn't reloading, and is throwing the error no ssl_certificate_key given. Please explain this

Answer (score 5):

## Letsencrypt: `fullchain.pem`

Same trouble for me. I was using Letsencrypt and, in my Nginx configuration, I needed to NOT use this:

```
ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key   /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem;
```

But use this:

```
ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key   /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem;
```

Comment: Nice! That worked. However I am trying to set up OCSP stapling and I don't know which file I shall use for ssl_trusted_certificate. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: @france1 Probably to `full_chain.pem` https://support.globalsign.com/ssl/ssl-certificates-installation/nginx-enable-ocsp-stapling & https://sectigo.com/knowledge-base/detail/Enable-OCSP-Stapling-on-NGINX-1527076084670/kA01N000000zFJk.

Comment: I didn't have to add ssl_trusted_certificate because fullchain.pem was already specified in ssl_certificate - it works now :)

Comment: @france1 I think that was the issue for me also, with the same conclusion