# Including intermediate certificates from Letsencrypt in Nginx SSL setup

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, telegram-webhook

I test my SSL setup using the [SSL Labs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) which says that **certificate chain is incomplete** (no other problems otherwise). That seems about right since I can't get Telegram webhooks to work (great explanation in the [Telegram webhook guide](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#supplying-an-intermediate-certificate)).

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750890/nginx-install-intermediate-certificate/25769829), when setting up SSL certificates using Nginx, I need to get *all* certificates (including intermediate ones) *in order*. I'm using Let's Encrypt ([letsencrypt.org/certificates](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/)) and I'm trying to figure out what the correct order of certificates would be.

I've tried concatenating `cat cert.pem lets-encrypt-r3.pem > bundle.pem` and using `bundle.pem` but no luck. Perhaps more intermediate certificates of the ones listed on [letsencrypt.org/certificates](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) should be included but it's unclear to me *which ones* and *in what order*.

I would be very grateful for any hints or pointers on where to read up more!

Comment: Instead of `cert.pem` use `fullchain.pem` which already includes all of the intermediate certificates and your certificate in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That was the first thing I'd tried and got me *certificate chain is incomplete* on SSL Labs in the first place. Can you think of anything else I could double check?

Answer (score 1):

With Certbot-generated certificates you don't need to concatenate anything. Use the following configuration:

```
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
```